# Is there software akin to an "ultimate" decompiler that will work for any language?

Tags: language-agnostic, decompiling, decompiler

I do *not* know what language a program was written in, but I'd like to find a decompiler that can decompile its source code *and* find it out what language it was written in.

If it is made in pascal, c, bas, vb, qb or something this way and decode/save as a readable .src

Something like exe2bin or exe2src
I have a coupple DOS-programs, I think were made in pascal. I need to decompile these programs so I can make them a Win32 application.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Even if it *were* possible, you'd probably run seriously afoul of licensing agreements.

Comment: "not possible"? That's a brave call, @Oli :-) While incredibly difficult, I'd draw the line at the impossibility tag.

Comment: @pax: To unambiguously determine the source language from a raw binary?  I'd like to think I'm safe in saying that that's "impossible"!

Comment: In general it is indeed impossible, practically, there might be something like compiler specific footprint - e.g. used optimisations, data representation etc. Imagine the original Pascal strings, lack of vararg calls in Pascal, stack frames...

Answer (score 6):

Hexrays http://www.hex-rays.com/decompiler.shtml is a product that decompiles any Windows executable to C source code. More than any other decompiler, it does not achieve a roundtrip decompilation -- depending on the language, it may be more or less impossible to reconstruct the program from the decompiled source.

For some languages this is easier than for others. E.g. .NET languages have Reflector, and I believe I've seen something similar for VB6.

Comment: More than likely, what you've seen for VB 6 will only work if the program was compiled to pseudo-code (P-Code). If it was compiled to native code, the best you're going to do is probably a hex dump. You won't see any VB 6 code!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for some sort of "theory of everything" decompiler. There is no such thing. If you have any doubts, give a thought to this:

> Why is closed source software different than open source software?

The answer is, of course, that you cannot see the source code of a closed source program ;) You may try with existing decompilers, but there is no guarantee you will succeed, which you seem to expect.

Comment: Theoretically, you can get platform specific machine code from any program, cracks are the proof:)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a decompiler that takes any type of binary and translates it to a single higher-level language, albeit impractical in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

A skilled human can look at the .exe with a hex file viewer. Most compilers leave their identity pretty clearly in the strings in the program.

A program to do that, now that's harder.