# Decompiler python et al

Tags: python, language-agnostic, decompiler

For python3 so far there isnt a stable working decompiler. The closest thing is unpyc3 which is buggy at best. I want to create a decompiler which can work for python but how would I go about it? Though I want to create it in python is it possible to have a global decompiler which works for all languages? If a program has access to all the libraries of a given language and is given a compiled file is it possible to break it into any language can the computer do that? It is working with machine language so should this matter in a decompilation?

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for a way to convert python bytecode (pyc files) into python source code?

Comment: yes thats what i want to do isnt pyc files compiled python source?

Comment: @mgilson Python is compiled to bytecode at runtime, then executed on a virtual machine. It's compiled (or not) in exactly the same way as Java.

Comment: .pyc files are faster to lex. Nothing else.

Comment: well is there a way to get a .py out of a .pyc?

Comment: @user1775641: You might get back to *a* .py file, but it may not look much like the original. There are [tools](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html) (including one [online](http://utilitymill.com/utility/pyc_xray)) to look at the contents. This should at least give an idea of how distantly a .pyc file resembles the original source code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there software akin to an "ultimate" decompiler that will work for any language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842654/is-there-software-akin-to-an-ultimate-decompiler-that-will-work-for-any-langua)

Answer (score 0):

[uncompyle6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncompyle6) is pretty good and works for Python 3.

As for your question of how to write to do this in general, see its wiki which describes [how it works](https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6/wiki/How-does-this-code-work%3F).

However I'll outline the steps below.

You first need to understand how to read an "executable" which could contain machine code for a particular CPU type, or bytecode for a virtual machine. *Uncompyle6* uses a grammar to reconstruct the program. The disassembled machine instructions are is called in parsing terminology "tokens". For example, instead of "token: number with value 5" you'd have "`LOAD_CONST` instruction with value 5".

After this you probably want understand control flow. And for that typically basic blocks, or straight-line code are determined. You can now do this since you grok which tokens are jump instructions.

The basic idea uncompyle6 uses  is to add tokens to a grammar to allow the grammar to detect control flow. So roughly it might see:

```
SETUP_LOOP
JUMP_IF FALSE X
... 
X:
```

And add something at X to indicate that's the end:

```
SETUP_LOOP
JUMP_IF_FALSE X
...
COME_FROM_LOOP # this is added
```

Inside each basic block you can then build up an abstract syntax tree (AST) for expressions and statements inside the basic block. The approach used in *uncompyle6* is to use a context-free grammar. Other Python3 programs like *pycdc* or the program *unpyc3* you cite don't do that. Instead then build up the tree using a stack, and a linear scan of the instructions. To give some idea of this

```
 LOAD a    # tree/stack: | a
 LOAD b    # tree/stack: | b, a
 LOAD c    # tree/stack: | c, b, a 
 ADD       # tree/stack: (c + b) |  a
 MULTIPLY  # tree/stack: (c + b) * a
 STORE d   # tree/stack: d = (c + b) * a |
```

Perhaps you can see how a grammar would do the same thing.

Having said this and suggesting *uncompyle6*, I'll say that right now it is pretty weak on the control flow analysis part which is largely ad hoc.

Since you express interest in creating a decompiler, how about instead contributing to an existing compiler to make it better?